# Add permission to facebook app

Tags: facebook

I want to develop a facebook app that assits in page managing.
I learned that facebook recently change 'extended permission' such as 'manage_pages' to be available
only after submission and their approval.
What I don't understand is - how can I develop my app and submit it without having a way to test it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approval is excluded for developers, beta users (real users) and test user accounts (fictional users) of the app. Approval is required if you wish to prompt general users that permission.